# Implement Groups and Group admins on Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, organic-groups

I'm new to Drupal and I'd like to get this quickly implemented, or at least know if it is possible and how to proceed.

This is the situation:
3 types of users (roles): SuperAdmin, GroupAdmin and user.

Users are just users who can use the whole site.
GroupAdmin has the ability to create users associated to his Group. They can administer only users from his group.
SuperAdmin can administer all kind of accounts.

Any info on how to get started would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module yet.  If you implement this along with Organic Groups Access Control it should give you what you are looking for.

Here's a tutorial on setting it up: [Organic Groups: Enable users to create collaborative groups](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/og)

Comment: I was aware of that module, but I thought maybe it was too much for my needs. And, I need to learn how to work on top of it. Anyways, it seems the right way to go, thanks.

Comment: Also, this groups are going to be dynamically created, is this possible?